# Picking notable words from dictionary

Tags: swift, algorithm

I see many iOS apps on the line of word of the day. I am in the process of making one such swift iOS app but picking a random word from dictionary mostly picks lousy words. Above said apps seem to pick useful notable words which would have learning value.

My question is, how can I improve my random function so that the picked words are notable?

Comment: check tf-idf weighting -- you ccould use that to improve your random picking function

Comment: thats a good direction to start, but not sure where this frequency data will be available for whole english dictionary

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to assign to each word in your dictionary a weight. The weight (or probability of being selected) could be the inverse of the probability of appearing in a corpus. In order to do that, you need a *corpus* (or a large chunk of text) and compute the frequency of each word in that text (but you can also use available corpora (there's a list here: http://corpus.byu.edu/).

The words that are more "rare" might be the most valuable and have the highest learning value.